Looking for dystopian novel with a terraplane race
I have a memory of reading a book (in English) in school in the UK during the mid-90s (probably '94 and definitely no later than '96), that was set in a dystopian future, but can't remember the name or the main plot!
What I do remember is that the protagonist is a young male from a lower class in society that somehow manages to get the other side of the fence amongst the upper class.
The main thing I remember about this story - as it was the focus of group project in class - is that some point in the early part of the story was a 'terraplane' race, though I believe this to be an almost insignificant part of the story and hasn't helped me in successfully searching for the story.
Another frustration is that I seem to recall stumbling across the book several years ago as an answer on this site, but despite a number of searches I can't find it again, so it is likely that this question will be a duplicate!

Aside: a terraplane is an actual automobile. There's even a dystopian science fiction novel by Jack Womack titled Tarraplane.

As I discovered when trying to search for this book initially! It seems that Google is very much aware novel as that is all that seemed to come up when searching for "dystopian novel terraplane race"!

And moments later I have found it! It is The Guardians by John Christopher, as found in this answer.
It was found after writing this question and adding the 'dystopia' tag - something I hadn't focussed on before - and then searching for that tag on this site!
Seeing the word 'Conurbs' in the book description immediately rang a bell, and then doing a Google search for 'the guardians John Christopher terra-plane' revealed a result that mentioned

terraplaning where jet-propelled cars hurtle round a cambered track, occasionally crashing

Which is exactly what I remember in the book.
